# Changing value of xml node using jquery

Tags: jquery

This is very  simple question, but i'm getting struggle in this from last 4 hours. I'm having xml file like(getting xml from service)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ratepanel>
  <mcx_bid>29500.00</mcx_bid>
  <mcx_ask>29715.00</mcx_ask>
  <mcx_ltp>0.00</mcx_ltp>
  <mcx_open>0.00</mcx_open>
  <mcx_high>30125.00</mcx_high>
  <mcx_low>29539.00</mcx_low>
  <mcx_time>26/02/2014 13:49:47</mcx_time>
  <trade_type>1</trade_type> //it will be 0(or)1(or)2(or)3
</ratepanel>
```

in some rare case i'm getting xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ratepanel>
  <mcx_bid>29500.00</mcx_bid>
  <mcx_ask>29715.00</mcx_ask>
  <mcx_ltp>0.00</mcx_ltp>
  <mcx_open>0.00</mcx_open>
  <mcx_high>30125.00</mcx_high>
  <mcx_low>29539.00</mcx_low>
  <mcx_time>26/02/2014 13:49:47</mcx_time>
  </trade_type>
</ratepanel>
```

and i'm using this xml in jquery like

```
$.ajax({                        
            type: "POST",                      
            url: "urlofsource",
            data: "",
            success: function(xmlDoc){
                $("mcx_bid").val(Math.round($(xmlDoc).find('mcx_bid').text()));
                $("mcx_ask").val(Math.round($(xmlDoc).find('mcx_ask').text()));
                        if($(xmlDoc).find('trade_type').text() == 1){
                           -- some activity                         
                        }
                .
                .
                .
```

if in xml trade_type node contain value means i don't have any problem, But xml trade_type node looks like (it mean without value) means how to set default as 0 in jquery.
I tried like

```
if($(xmlDoc).find('trade_type').text() == ''){
                 $(xmlDoc).find('trade_type').text(0);
                console.log($(xmlDoc).find('trade_type'));
             }
```

but in console print null value. How to set value for xml node using jquery. Please help any one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(xmlDoc).find('trade_type').text() == ''){
    $(this).text('0');
     console.log($(this).text());
}
```

Missing **text()** in the end of the trade_type selector inside console.log

Comment: if i use this getting error like Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createDocumentFragment'